# Is there a way to filter Customers on Shopify by metafield value through the REST Admin API?

Tags: python, shopify, shopify-api

I am trying to get Shopify Customers by VAT Number which is a metafield. Apparently there's no way to do it.

I have gone through the docs and GitHub repository and tried all the possible solutions through REST and GraphQL.

Answer (score 0):

So you are given a VAT number. You want the customer that has a metafield with the vat number?

Why would you not just ask for the metafield VAT value and search all Customers for a match?

```
metafield(namespace: "mystore", key: "vat") {
  value
}
```

Sure, it's a bit inefficient to search all Customers, but you do succeed in the end.

Comment: That wouldn't be possible because the number of Customers is too high.

Comment: Realistically, your only search criteria is email. Use that, and you get their VAT.